useEffect not running on page load
When you log in and go to the main runs page, it should get the runs (JSON data type) from your account (in mysql database) and display them through a useEffect, but the useEffect does not seem to be running. Also when I try to add a new run, it adds it to the database but returns and error saying
TypeError: runs.map is not a function
at DisplayRuns
In DisplayRuns, it should be mapping each run in the array to a react component that displays on screen.
displayRuns.jsx
export default function DisplayRuns({ runs, removeRun }) {
  return (
    <div>
//The .map in question \/
      {runs.map((run, index) => (
        <div key={`${run}` + `${run.index}`} className="runWrapper">
          <div className="run runIndex">Run {index + 1}</div>
          <div className="run runDistance">Distance: {run.distance} {run.distanceType}</div>
          <div className="run runTime">Time: {run.minutes}:{run.seconds}</div>
          <div className="run runSpeed">Speed: {run.calcSpeed()}</div>
          <div className="run runDate">Date: {run.date}</div>
          <button onClick={() => removeRun(run.index)} className="runRemoveBut">Remove</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

runs.jsx
import React from "react";
import { ReactDOM } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import AddRun from "./addRun";
import DisplayRuns from "./displayRuns";
import axios from 'axios'
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { setBackendRuns } from "../store/authSlice"
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Main() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const loggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isLoggedIn)
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user)

  const [runs, setRuns] = useState([])
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)


// This isnt firing at all \/
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/get-runs', {params: {user}})
    .then(res => {
      let runs = []
      res.data.forEach(run => runs.push(run))
      if (runs == undefined) {
        return
      } else {
        setRuns(runs)
      }
      setError(null)
      console.log(runs)
    })
    .catch(err => setError('Couldnt fetch users'))
  }, [user]); 

  function openForm () {
    setShowForm(!showForm)
  }

  function handleClick () {
    setShowForm(!showForm)
    dispatch(setBackendRuns({ username: user, runs: runs }));
  }

  const addRun = (minutes, seconds, distance, distanceType, date) => {
    let newRun = {
      minutes,
      seconds,
      distance,
      distanceType,
      index: (runs.length + 1),
      date,
      calcSpeed: () => {
        const timeInSeconds = Number(minutes) * 60 + Number(seconds);
        const speed = distanceType === "Kilometres"
          ? distance / (timeInSeconds / 3600)
          : distance / (timeInSeconds / 3600) * 1.60934; // Miles to km
        return distanceType === "Kilometres" ? `${speed.toFixed(2)} Km/h` : `${speed.toFixed(2)} mph`;
      }
    };
    newRun.index = (runs.length + 1) + newRun;
    setRuns(runs.push(newRun));
    setShowForm(false);
    console.log("Updated runs array:", runs); // Add this log
  };

  const removeRun = (index) => {
    setRuns(runs.filter((run) => run.index !== index));
    dispatch(setBackendRuns({ username: user, runs: runs }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="allWrapper">
      <div>
        <button onClick={openForm} className="openFormBut">Add new</button>
      </div>
      {showForm && (<AddRun addRun={addRun} closeForm={handleClick}/>)}
      <DisplayRuns runs={runs} removeRun={removeRun} />
      {!loggedIn ? <Navigate to='/signup' replace={true} /> : null}
    </div>
  )
}

Git repo: https://github.com/ReeperC3/Run-Tracker-II
The run-tracker-2 folder is the frontend and the server folder is the backend
I tried console.logs to see what the issue was but I can't figure out where it is going wrong.

Imports from the same package you could be adding them like import { ReactDOM, useState, useEffect } from "react;

For the useEffect hook, the problem is that you declared an action you are not invoking. There are two basic ways to do this and I will try to show code examples of what that will look like.
You can either try self-invokng functions or just create a function that does this action in the useEffect and call it
Example 1:
useEffect(() => {
(function() {
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/get-runs', {params: {user}})
.then(res => {
  let runs = []
  res.data.forEach(run => runs.push(run))
  if (runs == undefined) {
    return
  } else {
    setRuns(runs)
  }
  setError(null)
  console.log(runs)
})
.catch(err => setError('Couldnt fetch users'))
 })()

  }, [user]); 

Example 2:
useEffect(() => {
const runsData = () => {
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/get-runs', {params: {user}})
.then(res => {
  let runs = []
  res.data.forEach(run => runs.push(run))
  if (runs == undefined) {
    return
  } else {
    setRuns(runs)
  }
  setError(null)
  console.log(runs)
})
.catch(err => setError('Couldnt fetch users'))
 }
 
 runsData()

 }, [user]); 

You can take step two a step further and place it in an if statement so that it only fires when the user information is available.
I hope this helps you in your journey to finding a solution

Either this did not work, or it is returning undefined because still nothing is changing. Anyway, I still have the issue of the runs.map returning as not a function which is stopping them from being displayed at all

No matter what I seem to do I can tell that it is not firing because any console.logs within it are not running and showing up in the console

try to remove this part of the code if (runs == undefined) {return} and see what the error is returned when you try to fetch the data from Axios. Also, log out the result from the res result to see if the right information is coming back

The same issue occurs, the useEffect just doesn't seem to be running
